# %s error when trying to put a variable into a string python

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to build a "launcher" type thing for youtube-dl(program that lets you download youtube videos), and getting an error. I understand what the error means but it makes no sense as I am(I think) doing exactly what python wants.

This is my code:

```
import os
import sys
x = input('Enter link for youtube Video you would like to download: ')
ytdp = open('C:\\Games\\ytdp.bat', 'w')
ytdp.write('cd C:\\Users\Jake\Music')
ytdp.write('\n')
ytdp.write('youtube-dl %s')% (x)
ytdp.close()
os.startfile('C:\\Games\ytdp.bat')
sys.exit()
```

This is the error I get when running the code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jake\Desktop\Youtube video downloader.py", line 8, in <module>
    ytdp.write('youtube-dl %s')% (xx)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 0):

`ytdp.write('youtube-dl %s')% (xx)`

Should be

`ytdp.write('youtube-dl %s'% (xx))`

[Here](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/formatting_strings.html) is some more info on it